# Asynchronous File I/O using FileStream is blocking UI thread on WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, async-await

I am trying to copy from one folder to another folder and following the msdn [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys(v=vs.110).aspx) I tried to implement an asnyc call on my WPF application. But I am not sure what I am doing wrong it blocks UI thread and I dont think this first sample is asnyc.

here is my code

```
  Dim tasks = myImages.Select(Async Function(x)
                                                Dim result As Image
                                                Try

                                                    result = Await CopyImage(x, If(cts IsNot Nothing, cts.Token, Nothing))

                                                Catch ex2 As Exception

                                                End Try

                                                ProgressValue += 1
                                                CompletedText = ProgressValue.ToString() & " of " + MaxValue.ToString() & " images completed."
                                                Return result
                                            End Function)
                Dim results = Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)

  Public Async Function CopyImage(Image As Image, ct As CancellationToken) As Task(Of Image)
    If ct.IsCancellationRequested Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Await _mutex.WaitAsync()
    Dim SourceMainDirectory As String = "\\Server\Folder1"
    Dim DestinationMainDirectory As String = = "\\Server\Folder2"

    Dim Path = Image.Path.Replace("/", "\")
    Dim Data As String() = Path.Split("\")
    Dim Folder As String
    Dim ImageName As String
    If Data IsNot Nothing AndAlso Data.Length > 1 Then
        Folder = Data(0)
        ImageName = Data(1)      
    End If

    Dim ImgFullSource = SourceMainDirectory + Folder + "\" + ImageName
    Dim ImgFullDest = DestinationMainDirectory + Folder + "\" + ImageName

    Try

        Using SourceStream As FileStream = File.Open(ImgFullSource, FileMode.Open)
            Using DestinationStream As FileStream = File.Create(ImgFullDest)
                Await SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream, 81920, ct)
                Return Image
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
        Return Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        _mutex.Release()
    End Try

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

ProgressValue above is raised to update my progressbar Value. This Code works fine without blocking UI thread and perfectly updates progress asynchronously If I use myHttpClient.GetAsync method to verify same images on the web, for example

```
  Dim tasks = myImages.Select(Async Function(x)
                                                Dim result As Image
                                                Try

  result = Await  testUrl_async_cancel(x, If(cts IsNot Nothing, cts.Token, Nothing))
                                                Catch ex2 As Exception

                                                End Try

                                                ProgressValue += 1
                                                CompletedText = ProgressValue.ToString() & " of " + MaxValue.ToString() & " images completed."
                                                Return result
                                            End Function)
                Dim results = Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)

  Async Function testUrl_async_cancel( ByVal myImage As Image, ByVal ct As CancellationToken) As Task(Of AEL)

        If ct.IsCancellationRequested Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Await _mutex.WaitAsync()

        Dim myHttpClient As New HttpClient()
        Dim myHttpResponse As HttpResponseMessage

 myHttpClient.BaseAddress = New Uri(imageUrlD)


        Try
            myHttpResponse = Await myHttpClient.GetAsync(myImageUrl, ct)
        Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
            myHttpResponse = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            myHttpResponse = Nothing
        Finally
            _mutex.Release()
        End Try

        If myHttpResponse IsNot Nothing AndAlso myHttpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
            Return Nothing
        Else
            Return myImage
        End If


    End Function
```

So it should be something to do with the CopyImage function and respectively using the sourcestream what blocks the UI thread as all other code is the same. How can I make this code async that wont block the UI thread on WPF?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is due to an oddity in file streams. `File.Open` and `File.Create` can only return *synchronous* file streams.

To get a truly asynchronous file stream, you have to use the [`FileStream` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) and either pass `true` for the `isAsync` parameter, or include the `FileOptions.Asynchronous` flag in the `options` parameter. You *must* call a constructor overload with either `isAsync` or `options`, or else the file stream will be synchronous.

Comment: awsome. it works like a charm. I accept your answer and add also my code changes as answer below. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

based on Stephen Cleary's answer. I changed the filestream read and write part as following and it works async without blocking the UI thread. I hope this helps anyone else looking for same solution.

last parameter **True is the async** parameter as Stephen mentioned.

```
 Using SourceStream As FileStream = New FileStream(ImgFullSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 81920, True)
                Using DestinationStream As FileStream = New FileStream(ImgFullDest, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, 81920, True)
                    Await SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream, 81920, ct)
                    Return Image
                End Using
            End Using
```